# Primefaces TabChangeEvent doesn't fire

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm running a project with JSF 2.2 (Mojarra) and Primefaces 3.5 on a weblogic 10.3.6.

Here is a piece of my code.

```
<ui:composition>
    <ui:define>
        ...
        <p:layout>
            <p:layoutUnit id="filters">
                <h:form id="form_filters">
                ...
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit id="Tabs">
                <h:form id="form_tabs">
                    <p:tabView id="tw" 
                            dynamic="true" 
                            cache="false" 
                            onTabShow="handleTab();"
                            activeIndex="#{research.tabIndex}">

                            <p:ajax event="tabChange" 
                                listener="#{research.onTabChange}" 
                                partialSubmit="true" 
                                process="tw"/>

                            <p:tab id="Included" title="#{msg['research.tab.included']}" 
                                rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER, ROLE_TECNICAL_TEAM')}" > 
                                <h:panelGroup id="included_table" styleClass="scrollable" 
                                    layout="block" 
                                    rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER, ROLE_TECNICAL_TEAM')}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/research/include_table.xhtml" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab id="Reviewed" title="#{msg['research.tab.reviewed']}" 
                                rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER, ROLE_REGISTRATION, ROLE_SUPPLIES')}">
                                <h:panelGroup id="reviewed_table" styleClass="scrollable" 
                                    layout="block" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER')}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/research/all_table.xhtml" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGroup id="registration_reviewed_table" styleClass="scrollable" 
                                    layout="block" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ROLE_REGISTRATION, ROLE_SUPPLIES')}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/research/registration_reviewed_table.xhtml" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </p:tab>
                        </p:tabView>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My problem is:

I filter some data that is inside(a p:datatable) of the tab 1(Included). When I click on the tab 2(Reviewed) the tabChange event does not fire. But If I filter again and change tabs, the event reponds.

Do you have any hints?

If you need more code or have some questions, please tell me!

best regards!

Comment: what happens when you remove the partialSubmit?

Comment: @raylee. Sorry for the delay. Nothing change when I remove the partialSubmit.

Comment: shouldn't onTabShow contain an el? Or did you define JS somewhere?